adf copy data tool - mongo db filtering
I have a collection in Mongo called 'collectionX'. I want to query whole data, except I want to filter out by event_date that is after July 1st (event, creationdate - unix milisecond timestamp). However I am using this query in azure data copy tool and I get an error of an invalid use of filtering.
db.CollectionX.find({
  "events": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "creationDate.$date": { "$gt": NumberLong(1725072000000) }
    }
  }
})

Tried multiple queries, do I write Mongo queries here or something else?
json structure ->
  "_identitificationID": {
    "$originalID": "xyz123"
  },
  "events": [
    {
      "_identificationID": {
        "$originalID": "xyz1234"
      },
      "messageId": "thatsmymessage",
      "creationDate": {
        "$date": 1671023788998
      },
      "myinformationID": "abc",
      "otherinfo": "123",
      "eventname": "somethinghappened"
    },


Does creationDate actually contain a document with a field $date?

added hierarchy

{"$date": 1671023788998} looks like MongoDB extended JSON.  JSON doesn't have a Date datatype, so that may indicate that the field actually contains a UTC datetime.
